# How can I show out some message into GridLayout by using KeyListener

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

In my class file, I have some JTextField which added some KeyListener on it. I wish to have the message show up when the user typed into the JTextField.

But because I'm using GridLayout(2 rows, 1 column), I want the message show up at the second cell of the GridLayout.

This is my code:

```
JPanel xInputPanelLeft = new JPanel();
xTextField1 = new JTextField(5);
xInputPanelLeft.add(new JLabel("Center X: "));
xInputPanelLeft.add(xTextField1);
xTextField1.addKeyListener(this);
```

My error message show up: (At second row)

```
errorPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
errorMessage = new JLabel();
errorMessage.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,15));
errorMessage.setForeground(Color.RED);
```

My Event:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==xTextField1){
        try{
            drawCircle.centerX1 = Integer.parseInt(xTextField1.getText());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException error){
            errorMessage.setText("Invalid Input Type");
        }
        redraw.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==xTextField1){
        try{
            drawCircle.centerX1 = Integer.parseInt(xTextField1.getText());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException error){
            errorMessage.setText("Invalid Input Type");
        }
        redraw.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource()==xTextField1){
        try{
            drawCircle.centerX1 = Integer.parseInt(xTextField1.getText());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException error){
            errorMessage.setText("Invalid Input Type");
        }
        redraw.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. But for a **`JTextComponent`**, use an even more specific listener, a `DocumentListener`.

Comment: `errorPanel` should use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/CardLayout.html), and you should add a blank JLabel as a second child.  When you want the message hidden, [show](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show(java.awt.Container,java.lang.String)) the blank JLabel;  when you want the message shown, show `errorMessage`.